# Particular solution of system of nonhomogeneus differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am asked to find the solution of the following system of nonhomogeneus differential equations using elimination method:

$$ \begin{cases}
x'(t)=4x(t)-2y(t)+t^{-3} \\
y'(t)=8x(t)-4y(t)-t^{-2}
\end{cases} $$

By differentiating the first equation and substituing in values from second one, I find the characteristic value which is $ \lambda_{1,2} = 0 $, but from there on I am not sure how to proceed.

I believe the solution of the homogeneus equation for $x(t)$ is $ x_{0}(t) = C_1e^{0t} = C_1 $, but I do not know in what form should I seek a particular solution. Some help or hints on what to do would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: There is a mistake in the system an x instead of an y

Comment: Oh yes, thank you, I corrected it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{cases}
x'(t)=4x(t)-2y(t)+t^{-3} \\
y'(t)=8x(t)-4y(t)-t^{-2}
\end{cases}$$
Substract both DEs
$$2x'-y'=2t^{-3}+t^{-2}$$
Integrate:
$$2x-y=-t^{-2}-t^{-1}+C_1$$
$$4x-2y=-2t^{-2}-2t^{-1}+2C_1$$
Now eliminate $4x-2y$ from first equation and solve for $x(t)$. It's a first DE.

---

If you have 2 times an eignanvalue equals zero then the solution should be $c_1+c_2t$ But you didnt post your attempt so we can check it.

Comment: Oh, I think I will manage it now, thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome @grinch